# "zsh: command not found: adb" after adding ANDROID_HOME and PATH variables to .zshrc

Tags: adb, zsh, android-sdk-manager

I'm trying to run a React Native app through Expo Go using `npm expo start`.

I've installed Android Studio and located my Android SDK folder in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`, then added this path to the ANDROID_HOME and PATH variables in `.zshrc` as follows:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/../../mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$PATH
```

After reloading with `source ~/.zshrc` I try to run `adb` in the terminal and get:

```
zsh: command not found: adb
```

*However*, I can run adb directly with `$HOME/../../mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe` (I have to add the .exe explicitly or else it won't run).

I suspect that I may have added the incorrect paths in `.zshrc`, added them to the wrong file, or that the SDK folder is in the wrong place.

I've looked over several similar issues, which all recommend adding the same PATH variables despite many people having their SDK folders located differently (in `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk`, for example).

I'm still very new to Android Studio and adding PATH variables, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post `echo $PATH` after sourcing `~/.zshrc`.

Comment: Here's everything I get with `echo $PATH` that's related to the Android/Sdk path:

`/home/nexus/../../mnt/c/Users/nexus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/nexus/../../mnt/c/Users/nexus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/nexus/../../mnt/c/Users/nexus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:/home/nexus/bin:/usr/local/bin:/home/nexus/../../mnt/c/Users/nexus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools/bin:/home/nexus/../../mnt/c/Users/nexus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/tools:/home/nexus/../../mnt/c/Users/nexus/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:`

Comment: Does `adb.exe` have execute permissions (`ls -l $HOME/../../mnt/c/Users/username/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe`)? Did you try running `adb.exe` instead of `adb`?

Comment: Yes, it should have execute permissions; running that command I can see `-rwxrwxrwx` for `adb.exe`. Now that you've mentioned it, running `adb.exe` instead of `adb` does work. Is there something I'm maybe missing to allow the executable to run without the ".exe" extension? Thank you for the help so far.

Comment: Usually you type the **name** of command to invoke it; hence, if your command is named _adb.exe_, you run int by typing its name and not just part of the name. If it is too much typing for you, consider defining an alias, function or symlink named `adb` (i.e. 'alias a=adb.exe' would allow you to run it by typing just _a_).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run `adb.exe` in shell as `adb` you have the following options (pick one of them):

- Create a symlink:

```
cd platform-tools
ln -s adb.exe adb
```

- Create an alias. Put to `.zshrc`:

```
alias adb="adb.exe"
```

- Define a shell function. Put to `.zshrc`:

```
adb() {
  adb.exe $@
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Running `adb` now works. Only thing was that I had to change the function declaration from `adb()` to `function adb` in my `.zshrc` file to avoid getting a "()" parse error (according to this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369319/getting-defining-function-based-on-alias-z-error-everytime-open-the-terminal).

Comment: That's because you apparently created an alias and then tried to define a function with the same name. What I meant is that you need to use one of the options, not all three simultaneously.

Comment: Touché, my fault again. Thank you for catching the mistake again!